# Add row to datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

When I try add an extra row to my datagridview I get following error:

> **Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.**

Any idea to fix this, without databinding I added rows like this:

```
    ' Populate the rows.
    Dim row() As String = {omschrijving, aantalstr, eenheidsprijs, basisbedrag, kortingstr, kortingbedrag, netto, btw, btwbedrag, totaal, productid}

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: you should be adding data to the datasource if it is data bound

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your grid view is bound to a data object.  In that case, you need to add the row to the object it is bound to, like a dataset.

For instance, a rough example would be:

```
Dim boundSet As New DataSet

Dim newRow As DataRow = boundSet.Tables(0).NewRow
With newRow
    .Item(0) = "omschrijving"
    .Item(1) = "aantalstr"
    ...
End With

boundSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(newRow)
boundSet.AcceptChanges()
```

You would just need to use the dataset that was bound to your grid view instead of creating a new one.